# Print Successive Numbers That Appear Twice?

Tags: python

I want to print out each item in Python and number them successively, but each number should appear twice.

```
1 Item
1 Item
2 Item
2 Item
3 Item
3 Item
```

Comment: provide the desired output

Comment: This is a fun math problem. You just have to find a function `f` that makes `for idx, element in enumerate(seq): print f(idx), element` print out the numbers you want. So the challenge is, how do you map `0,1,2,3,4,5` to `1,1,2,2,3,3`? Hint: division is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = ['Item'] * 6
for i, item in enumerate(items, start=1):
    number = (i + 1) / 2
    print('{} {}'.format(number, item))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

From the docs:

> **enumerate**(*sequence*, *start=0*)
>
> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The next() method of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating...
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Example code:

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

for idx, item in enumerate(items):
  print idx, item
  print idx, item
```

Would yield the following output:

```
0 item1
0 item1
1 item2
1 item2
2 item3
2 item3
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

(If you're saying you only want them to appear once, omit one of the print statements.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    print i, item
    print i, item
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from his desired output, but I think OP wants to print each element of the list exactly once. so it would be "1 item1 \n 1 item2 \n 2 item3 \n 2 item4 \n 3 item5", etc.